# Prevent download file from extra tags

Tags: asp.net

I write small WebApp on ASP.NET, where I can upload files(data is stored in SQL FILESTREAM) and get it back. But, when I compare primary and download file in text editor there is difference. Extra tags are added in last one. Something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" > <head><title>    Untitled Page </title></head> ..............
```

I am downloading file with this parameters

> ```
> Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(path) + fileType);
>         Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
>         Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
> ```

Can anybody tell me how prevent download file from extra tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your response is not ended at the correct time.This causes the html from your page to also be posted as a download. Please add the following line after `Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);`

```
Response.End();
```